# how to send ajax request to codeigniter library file or class

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

ajax code

```
function autocomplet(){ 
      var countryname= $('#countrysearch').val();
        $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'My_commonlib',      //  My_commonlib is library file in library folder
    data: "countryname=" + countryname,
    success: function(data){ 
               }
             });
                }
```

html code

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="autocomplet()"  class="inputs form-control " style=" border-bottom: .5px solid;"  id="countrysearch" name="countrysearch" placeholder=" Search">
```

I send a request to  My_commonlib  in library folder

> php code

Pass ajax request to this class My_commonlib    or method getcountry

```
class My_commonlib   { 
      private $ci;
    public function __construct()
    {      
               $this->ci=& get_instance();
             $this->ci->load->database();

              // parent::__construct();
    }
       function getcountry(){
              $this->ci->db->from('countries');
              $this->ci->db->order_by("country", "ASC");
              return $this->ci->db->get()->result(); 
         }
 }
```

and get in view file as

```
$a = new My_commonlib();
     $results=$a->getcountry(); 
   foreach ($results as $row)
   {  ?>
        <a   href="<?php echo base_url('Country/detail/'.$row->country)?>"><?php echo $row->country ; ?></a><br> 
  <?php } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
url: 'My_commonlib',
```

to

```
url: '<?php echo base_url('My_commonlib/getcountry');?>',
```

Comment: after write your code show 404 Page Not Found   i send ajax request to library file  My_commonlib is library file and class

Comment: What was the earlier response ?

Comment: page not found 404

Comment: Please find the updated answer (replaced semi-colon with comma).

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter uses the url to decide which controller to load. You will *always* handle requests with a controller. The controller can be a very thin object that loads the library and passes the request on to it.